# data is not sending with GET method

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, get

I am using ajax to communicate with the server side. here is the code ,

My pages HTML

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="GET"> 
    <div class="form-group"> 
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="first_name">First Name :</label> 
        <div class="col-sm-4"> 
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="f_name" placeholder="Enter First Name">
        </div> 
    </div> 
    <div class="form-group"> 
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10"> 
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submit" onClick="process()">
             </button> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
</form>
```

The javascript

```
function process(){
var fname = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("f_name").value);
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"db.php?f_name="+fname,

        success:function(data){
            document.getElementById(infoTable).innerHTML = data;


        }
    })
});
}
```

my php code ,

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['f_name'];
echo $name;

?>
```

but i am getting the server response as undefined index . i have noticed that when i press the button, the url is not changing (i can't see the url with values).
Is there anything with the code or anything else ? please help, Thank you

Comment: `console.log(fname);` and I bet you'll find that it's empty.

Comment: Or look in the F12 tools network inspector and see the query string thats actually getting sent.

Comment: The whole HTML of your page would be helpful.

Comment: I tried console.log(fname) . its says undefined

Comment: <form class="form-horizontal" role="form"  method="GET">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2"     for="first_name">First  Name :</label>
     <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="f_name" placeholder="Enter First Name">
     </div>
    </div>
    
   <div class="form-group">
     
     <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submit" onClick="process()"></button>
     </div>
    </div>       
   </form>

Comment: Please dont paste code in a comment _It is totally unreadable_ Add it to your question

Comment: oops sorry . new to this site . sorry again !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of errors here.
Firstly, you don't need the `$(document).ready(function(){` since you want to send the ajax request when the user press the the submit button, not when the page is loaded.
Secondly, since you use an ajax, you should not really submit the form, you don't need to reload the page. So, you can change the `<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submit" onClick="process()"></button>` to `<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="submit" onClick="process()" value="Submit">`. BTW the `</button>` is odd here.

Comment: Thank u i solved the problem !! actually the error was in 
document.getElementById(infoTable).innerHTML = data;

missing " " marks in infotable !!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some changes that should get you on your way:

```js
var process = function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var fname = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("f_name").value);
console.log(fname);
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"db.php?f_name="+fname,

        success:function(data){
            document.getElementById(infoTable).innerHTML = data;


        }
    })
});
}


document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener(
    'click', process, false
);
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-4"> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="f_name" placeholder="Enter First Name"> </div> 

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submit">
```

Comment: Why do you think so? It has an event listener for clicking the submit button and then it does e.preventDefault(). Here's a fiddle with it working: https://jsfiddle.net/213pz7an/ Who knows why I got downvoted. So it goes.

Comment: As he isn't using any jquery calls inside that check other than ajax, probably not.